# servletContext.getRealPath("/") throws an error on app startup in controller

Tags: grails-controller, grails-3.0

I want to define an absolute app directory variable, which is accesible from every action within controller in which it is define (as normally it would be done in class constructor). I want to define it only once in controller scope. I tried to use beforeInterceptor:

```
class FileResourceController {

    def uploadPath = ""

    def beforeInterceptor = {
        uploadPath = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/") + "uploads" 
    }
}
```

but uploadPath ends up empty.

Simply doing this:

```
class FileResourceController {

    def uploadPath = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/") + "uploads"
}
```

throws an error on app startup.

Puting `def uploadPath = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/") + "uploads"` inside an action method works fine.

How can I define controller scope accessible absolute path variable in Grails?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `Holders.getServletContext()` there instead of `request.getSession().getServletContext()`.

Also, 'beforeInterceptors' in the controller is never called, because Grails 3 only supports standalone interceptors.

Comment: At first your solution didn't worked, but simply adding "import grails.util.Holders" made it work like a charm. Thank you!